# undefined error on vuejs2-touch-event

Tags: cordova, vuejs2, phonegap

I'm new in Vuejs 2. I'm trying to build a app using phonegap.  Recently i'm using vue2-touch-event and trying to handle some touch event. When user swipe left/right i'm passing extra parameter with the event.

Here is how i passed the parameter

```
<label v-touch:swipe.right="doneLisItem(index)">
</label>
```

Here is my code in the script

```
data() {
    return {
      newList: '',
      todoLists: [],
    };
},
methods: {
    doneLisItem(index) {
        return function(direction, event) {
            console.log(index);
            console.log(this.todoLists);
            if (!this.todoLists[index].completed) {
                this.todoLists[index].completed = true;
            }
        };
    },
}
```

The problem is i'm getting undefined in console.log(this.todoLists). Can anyone help me to solve this problem. TIA

Comment: maybe don't use a return function. Just use a normal function and use the same logic

Comment: @samayo If you pass a parameter to  vuejs2-touch-event handler function, you need to  use return function. Either it wont listen to the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the returned callback is invoked `this` does not point to the Vue instance . That's the reason you cannot access the data properties in and `undefined` is logged in the console.

So return an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that that `this` is bound lexically and points towards the vue instance

```
doneLisItem(index) {
    return (direction, event) => {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(this.todoLists);
        if (!this.todoLists[index].completed) {
            this.todoLists[index].completed = true;
        }
    };
},
```

Or you can make use of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) by declaring a variable pointing towards the correct vue instance variable inside the function

```
methods: {
    doneLisItem(index) {
        var vm = this; //now the Return function has a closure over vm which is the correct vue instance
        return function(direction, event) {
            console.log(index);
            console.log(vm.todoLists);
            if (vm.todoLists[index].completed) {
                vm.todoLists[index].completed = true;
            }
        };
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vamsi Krishna .. i tried this way before, maybe didn't work for another error. Thank you for your response.